# Find minimum number of rectangles of length 2 in a grid of binary values

Tags: algorithm, matrix, grid, greedy

Given a grid, I need to "cover" the **true** values with rectangles. The rectangles can only be horizontal or vertical and they can cover two cells at max.

For example, in this case:

```
1 1 1 0 0  
1 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 1 0
```

the minimum number of ractangles is 4: 1 from **[0][0]** to **[1][0]**, 2 from **[0][1]** to **[0][2]**, 3 with only **[1][4]** (since there aren't any adjacent 1s in the up, down, left and right directions) and the last one with only **[2][3]** in it.

I suppose, the problem comes when the grid has many consecutive 1s that split in many directions. For example

```
1 1 1 1 1
1 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 1 0
1 1 1 1 0
```

or

```
1 1 1
1 0 1
1 1 1
```

I cannot think of a pretty efficient algorithm to solve this problem, a greedy approach seems to be ineffective.

Any help would be really much appreciated, thanks.

EDIT:

The greedy algorithm I've tried: scan the matrix 1 row at a time, if there's a 1 in the current position, then check if there's another 1 in the next row position **[rowIndex][columnIndex + 1]** and "cover" both with one rectangle. If not, check the cell below the current position **[rowIndex + 1][columnIndex]** and  do as before. If there aren't any 1s in these positions, cover only the current cell. As you can see, this algorithm doesn't work in the first case. *Perhaps the algorithm must know all the consecutive 1s to compute the minimum number of rectangles. Because of this, I'm wondering if some graph stuff comes in, but I can't still think of an optimal solution.*

Comment: what are the constraints for the size of the grid?

Comment: Constraints can vary. It can be a squared grid, a A * B  grid or a B * A grid. A, B and the grid are dynamically defined. The purpose is to find an algorithm that solves grids of any size.

Comment: "grid of any size" doesn't make sense, what are maximum possible sizes for A and B in the task you are solving?

Comment: The greedy approach seems to work in all 3 of the cases you present. Perhaps you can discuss which greedy approach you're trying.

Comment: Try this: Take the `1` cell with the fewest number of `1` neighbors and connect it to one of its neighbors (if any) to create a rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply go through the matrix and as soon I see a 1 I try to create a new rectangle with an adjacent 1 which can be on the same line or row and has no other adjacent 1 otherwise the rectangle will cover only the current cell and then you scan the matrix until you find a new uncovered 1 or you have scanned the enteir matrix, in this way you can cover all the 1 with the minumum number of rectangle (if I'm not wrong).

```
for i=0 to N
   for j=0 to M
      if (1==matrix[i][j] AND notCovered(i,j)){
          k,l=adjacent(i,j)//return an adjacent 1 that cannot be covered, if all the adjacent 1 can be covered return the one on the same row
          if (k AND l == VOID ) 
                cover (i,j)
          else
                cover (i,j)(k,l)
       }
```

Of course you can do some improvement on this algorithm, I hope this will help you